# R Calculating relative differences between values that contain 0

Tags: r, compare, difference, standardization

I have a dataframe dat, which shows the number of daily visitors during certain days (case) and other days (control). I want to create now a 4th column, in which the difference between the Case and Control columns is being calculated for each Var. The problem is, that I dont want differences like +0.30 in that first case. I actually want something like +400%. But I have a lot of 0 in the Control column, so I always get Inf. numbers, which I dont want to have. How can I solve that problem?

```
  Var  Case Control
1  AB  0.40    0.10
2  TG  3.20    6.30
3  GF  0.23    0.18
4  ZH 14.00   14.00
5  ED  7.10    0.00
6  MS  5.50    5.60

dat <- data.frame(Var = c("AB", "TG", "GF", "ZH", "ED", "MS"),
                  Case = c(0.4, 3.2, 0.23, 14, 7.1, 5.5),
                  Control = c(0.1, 6.3, 0.18, 14, 0, 5.6))
```

Comment: What do you want instead of Inf? This is what it's supposed to be

Comment: This isn't a programming question. It's a question about how to represent ratios when the denominator can take a zero value. The answer is that you can't really do that. You need to decide, based on how you are using the information, what you want to do in these cases. Perhaps an `NA` is more appropriate than `Inf`? Perhaps exclude them from your data altogether? Perhaps get binomial confidence intervals on the raw numbers and take the lower confidence bound in these cases?

Comment: Ok, thanks! Do you think that z standardization might help? Or are those 0 still a problem?